Sci-fi book with girl and boy with powers and a mark and maybe Atlantis involved
Looking for a sci-fi YA novel. I remember the cover being blue. The main character is a rich girl—maybe a princess? And her family has a mark (I think it had something to do with stars? And it may have been on the hand?)
She goes out into the city and meets a boy who also has a mark on his hand (brains say mark is blue?) and they have powers? And something happens, and it turns out they're what's left of a race that came here on a ship, and I feel like they were on Atlantis because I think they mention the island sinking.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
